# Parsing XML with Object.keys()

Tags: json, xml-parsing

I have this XML that I trying to parse and to save into local storage:

```
<node>
   <external>
       <module>
          <id>1</id>
          <description>lorem</description>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
       </module>
       <module>
          <id>2</id>
          <description>lorem</description>
          <version>1.0.1</version>
       </module>
       ...
       <module></module>
   </external>
</node>
```

To parse it and store it as JSON I use:

```
$.get('myXml.xml', function(xml) { 
    var xml = $.xml2json(xml);
    var external = node.external;
    var externalModuleCount = Object.keys(external).length
}
```

I'm using `externalModuleCount` to get how many `<module>` tags I have inside of `<external>`. Problem is, `externalModuleCount`returns 1 even if there are 2 or more modules.

Does the `Object.keys()` function consider all tags with the same name as only one tag? How to get exact numbers of children tags ?

Thanks.

Comment: why you are chaging it into json. you directly save it into local storage through xml-parsing

Comment: I need JSON to work with an API